# assignment operator (=) within a function's parameter list?

Tags: php, function, parameters

I'm using the following code from PHPBuilder.com to handle user privileges on my site:

```
/**
 * Correct the variables stored in array.
 * @param    integer    $mask Integer of the bit
 * @return    array
 */
function bitMask($mask = 0) {
    if(!is_numeric($mask)) {
        return array();
    }
    $return = array();
    while ($mask > 0) {
        for($i = 0, $n = 0; $i <= $mask; $i = 1 * pow(2, $n), $n++) {
            $end = $i;
        }
        $return[] = $end;
        $mask = $mask - $end;
    }
    sort($return);
    return $return;
}
```

and I'm a bit baffled by the "= 0" part of `($mask = 0)` in the function parameter list. What does that do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that if you call the function like this:

```
$a = bitMask();
```

Then $mask will be set to `0`.

It is how you set default values to parameter in functions.

Example:

```
function example($a=0){
    echo "a = $a"; 
}

example(10);
example();
```

Output:

```
a = 10
a = 0
```

If `$a` did not have a default value set, then calling the function like `example()` would give a warning.

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php (Default argument values)

Answer (score 3):

That's the default value of $mask if no arguments are passed. This also prevents a warning from being generated when the parameter is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's response is correct. To add to it, take note that the assignment will not have an affect on the original variable modified. Here is his code with a few more assignments / echos to illustrate this:

```
function example($a=0){
    echo "Entering function: a = $a\n"; 
    $a = 3;
    echo "End of function: a = $a\n";
}

$a = 7;
example(10);
echo "Outside of Function: a = $a\n";
```

Outputs

```
Entering function: a = 10
End of function: a = 3
Outside of Function: a = 7
```